# how should I serve a .txt file off the root of my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a static route in my routes.rb:

`match ':action' => 'static#:action'`

And I have a file that's called `F97F5BF1DF45427AA9399E360EXXXXX.txt`. I need to provide access to this file for DCV validation for my SSL provider. I've tried a couple of locations and variations on the file name and still am not able to access the file via `http://mysite.com/F97F5BF1DF45427AA9399E360EXXXXX.txt`. Tried putting the file in public as well.

What do I need to do to provide access to that text file to any bot crawling the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should be able to serve it from the `public/` directory. But if that does not work, you can simply set up a new route in config/routes.rb:

```
match '/F97F5BF1DF45427AA9399E360EXXXXX' => "static#foobar"
```

And then create a new controller serving the file

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def foobar
    render "your file contents here"
  end
end
```